# responseText not returning HTML markup

Tags: php, html, ajax, innerhtml, responsetext

I have a web page where I am am using innerHTML and responseTEXT to replace the contents of a table upon user interaction. I am replacing the contents of a

`<div> {response html goes here} </div>`

The response HTML is a table that exists inside a  of its self.

So the preferred response would be:

```
`<div id="replaceContents"><div id="tableContaner></div></div>`
```

However when I make this call and have php echo the div back containing the table I just receive the text values, the response is missing all of the HTML markup.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript as well?

Answer (score 0):

if your JS looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText
```

then your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="container"><!-- place a loading gif here for example -->Replace ME</div>
```

You want to replace the contents within the container that has the ID of "container".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! my js looks just like that but what is being returned is not the echoed text including the HTML markup its just the raw values that go inside the html table cells

Comment: Can you access your ajax script directly from a browser and see what it outputs?

Comment: Hmm.. also might want to post more of your javascript. Does your response look like it's coming from your PHP script in which the AJAX is calling?

Comment: The php script I'm calling outputs correctly when I just load the page in a browser. I'm thinking that I have an extra div or table tag floating around.